# Dynamically creating variables in a forEach loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, database, foreach, var

So, I'm attempting to pass data through a `forEach` loop, creating a unique `var` for each piece of data passed. My code is as follows:

```
  data.forEach(function (data) {
    var name = data.Name;
  });
}
```

Is it possible to create a new 'name' `var` for each piece of `data.Name` data passed?

In other words: Is it possible to create a unique `var` and assign it dynamically to each name passed through the loop?

For example:

data set 1 is {Name: "Henry"}

data set 2 is {Name: "Chris"}

...

Is it then possible to make:

```
var1 = data set 1 ('Henry' )
var2 = data set 1 ('Chris')
...
```

By the way, an array doesn't work for my project, unfortunately. I'm attempting to isolate the individual data sets.

Thank you!

Comment: You really don't want to do that – put the values in an array.

Comment: It looks you need to use `map` instead please try this `const data = [{ Name: "John" }, { Name: "Ada" }, { Name: "Jill" }];

const names = data.map((entry) => entry.Name);

console.log(names);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you're attempting to store all of the names for later usage. If so you could probably go for something like:

```
var names = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
    names.push(d.Name);
});
```

Or simply:

```
var names = data.map(d => d.Name);
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a unique variable and assign it dynamically to each name passed through the loop?

Answer (score 3):

It *is* technically possible, using the `window` object for example. You could, dunno, do something like this

```
  data.forEach(function (item, index) {
    window["var" + index] = item.Name;
  });
}
```

But please, please, don't. Just `map` the `data` array into another array:

```
const namesArray = data.map(function(item) { 
    return item.Name; 
});
```

Comment: Great, Thank you.

Comment: Yes, but how do I access the item.Name individually instead of as an array, I want Name1 to act asynchronous of Name2 and Name3